# Is it bad form to use html class attribute as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering if the html class attribute should only be used for styling.  Is there any drawback to using the class attribute as a variable. The W3 spec http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes does not specify one way or another but, all examples and training point in the direction of styling only for multiple objects.

In my case I want to use the class attribute as variable that matches the key value in a object array.  For example in my Javascript code I have an object that has a number of key/value pairs. On my web app I have a number of save buttons.  When a save button is clicked I grab the parents class attribute value and use it as the key for the object to know which value to change.  The class attribute on the parent has not other value than to let me know which key value pair to change in my object

Comment: Classes should be semantic, not presentational. See [Step Away From the Presentational Classes](http://blog.terriblelabs.com/blog/2012/01/04/step-away-from-the-presentational-classes/)

Comment: Classes can be both semantic and presentational.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I'm sure it's *possible* to use classes that way, it's certainly not their intended purpose. html has data attributes that provide the functionality you want, for example

`<button data-key="some value" name="" id="">click me</button>`

You can then get that value (`onClick` if you like) and use it as a key for your object/data structure. Theres a [good overview here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I had the sense that this was not good form.

Answer (score 3):

While it is not bad, it neither is best practice.

You can, instead of using the class attribute, define explicit data attributes. Using the class attribute would mean that you could not use several classes (because that would be a weird key to search for in an object, right?).

For instance:

```
<div class="any classes you like" data-mykey="searchforthiskey">
  <button></button>
</div>
```

In jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var key = $(this).closest('div').attr('data-mykey');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From a functional perspective, there's no reason to NOT use the class attribute to store information about that element. You can access a class attribute as easily as you can a data attribute.

From a standards perspective, it is probably better to use a data attribute. Why? Well, if you are the only person working on your front-end, no big deal. If you are one of many on a team of front-end developers, who works specifically on the javascript side of things, you may run into a conflict with another front-end developer who works on the HTML/CSS side of things. They may remove a class from the element, not realizing that its also being used as your javascript hook into that element. In that case, you're better off creating your own data attribute, which then makes it clear that this attribute is probably data related and won't be molested by someone just trying to fix the styling of that element.